# reading a number of type double from a text file

Tags: c

I am still stuck on this problem, I have tried a lot of things to get it and still no success... All I am trying to do is read the number into one array and the letters into another. That way, I can call both at the same time to take a statistical analysis of the letter frequency of two books. I know how to do this for a string, but I want to only copy the input of the numbers, which are two spaces in front of the letter they represent. The code reads two files through the command prompt(argv[1] and argv[2]) and compares the two together take the root mean square(RMS) of the two as the output. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM_LETTERS 26
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    int ch, i, counter;
    double frequencysquared[NUM_LETTERS], freqone[NUM_LETTERS], freqtwo[NUM_LETTERS], average;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        freqone[ch] = fgets(/*unsure*/, 22, fp); 
    }
    while((ch=fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
    {
        freqtwo[ch] = fgets(/*unsure*/, 22, fp2);
    }
    while(i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        average += pow(( freqone[i]-freqtwo[i] ), 2);
    }
    average/=NUM_LETTERS;
    average = sqrt(average);
    printf("RMS Frequency: %lf", average);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Text file:

```
A 0.08030130328545595500
B 0.01404566680148545800
C 0.02309245337888202900
D 0.04680329046987134100
E 0.12475974957130967000
F 0.02262448732647651800
G 0.02092142515718645500
H 0.06495870199587520900
I 0.06832638626586488900
J 0.00118328558965393900
K 0.00796545073487383260
L 0.03678714564106335500
M 0.02553256208071077300
N 0.07071134182580297900
O 0.07759211410349403600
P 0.01653257210855475400
Q 0.00111309068179311220
R 0.06200383063640040700
S 0.06269909448568859700
T 0.09005003894146078300
U 0.02792921679195900500
V 0.00865068674018190480
W 0.02356209073861756000
X 0.00115988728703366340
Y 0.02033479628434954300
Z 0.00035933107595423293
```

Comment: Please describe what is wrong with the program you have, how you debugged it and what you found. And why does the program read from two files? That is not described in your question.

Comment: Just declare a buffer: `char my_buffer[MAX_LEN]; fgets(my_buffer, MAX_LEN, fp);` After that the string will be stored in `my_buffer`. Then use `strtod` to convert it to a double.

Comment: Do both text files look like the one above?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line 3) use spacing before a function declaration Suggest 2 blank lines

Comment: when calling system functions,  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this kind of line: `freqone[ch] = fgets(/*unsure*/, 22, fp);` is NOT how to write a call to `fgets()`,  Suggest: `while( ( ch=fgetc()) != EOF ) { // skipover space getchar(); freqone[ch] = fgets(freqone[ch-'A'], MAX_CHARS, fp);`  Where `#define MAX_CHARS (32)`  AND `char freqone[NUM_LETTERS][MAX_CHARS];`  Note: MAX_CHARS needs to be (at least) 2 or 3 characters longer than the data in the input file line, second field to allow for the '\n' and terminating NUL char.  I suggest 32 as that is a nice power of 2 value

Comment: the posted code, besides does not compile, has some undefined behavior due to no place to actually read the data into.

Comment: The posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 22.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: The posted code contains several unused variables and a syntax error.  This line: `while(i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++)` is not valid,  The `while()` statement has only a single parameter.  Suggest using: `for (i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++ )`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warning messages. then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: strongly suggest reading and understanding the man pages for any C keywords and any system functions that you use.

Comment: Very interesting why -wall isn't default... Turned it on and it was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do step at a time. Make the code as simple as possible. It is better to use a separate function to calculate the `RMS`, just because having everything in the main function can get overwhelming.

Here is some example code that will help you achieve your task:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUMLETTERS 26

#define RMS_VALID 1
#define RMS_INVALID 0

double calc_rms(double X[], double Y[], int n, double *rms);
void read_file(double numbers[], char letters[], FILE *stream);

int 
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    double numbers1[NUMLETTERS], numbers2[NUMLETTERS];
    char letters1[NUMLETTERS], letters2[NUMLETTERS];
    double rms;

    fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error Reading a File");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    read_file(numbers1, letters1, fp1);
    read_file(numbers2, letters2, fp2);

    if (calc_rms(numbers1, numbers2, NUMLETTERS, &rms) != RMS_INVALID) {
        printf("RMS Frequency: %f\n", rms);
    }

    return 0;
}

void
read_file(double numbers[], char letters[], FILE *stream) {
    double onedouble;
    char oneletter;
    int count = 0;

    while (fscanf(stream, " %c %lf", &oneletter, &onedouble) == 2) {
        numbers[count] = onedouble;
        letters[count] = oneletter;
        count++;
    }
}

double
calc_rms(double X[], double Y[], int n, double *rms) {
    int i;
    double sum = 0.0, diff;

    if (n <= 0) {
        return RMS_INVALID; // just for precaution
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        diff = (X[i] - Y[i]);
        sum += diff * diff;
    }
    *rms = sqrt(sum/n);
    return RMS_VALID;
}
```

Comment: Wow... I have a lot of studying to do, it seems so complicated, I hope it gets easier when I understand pointers more! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The rough outline of the program is on the right track, but you have many details wrong. For one, `scanf` can take care of getting the input. No need to fiddle with strings.

Also, you need much better error checking.

Here's a start:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE ('Z' - 'A' + 1)

void die(int err) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error %d\n", err);
  exit(err);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char ch;
  double f, a[SIZE], b[SIZE];
  FILE *fa, *fb;

  if (argc != 3) die(1);
  fa = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fa) die(2);
  fb = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  if (!fb) die(3);
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    a[i] = b[i] = -1.0;
  while (fscanf(fa, " %c%lf", &ch, &f) == 2)
    if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') a[ch - 'A'] = f; else die(4);
  fclose(fa);
  while (fscanf(fb, " %c%lf", &ch, &f) == 2)
    if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') b[ch - 'A'] = f; else die(5);
  fclose(fb);
  double sum_d2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    if (a[i] < 0 || b[i] < 0) die(100 + i);
    double d = a[i] - b[i];
    sum_d2 += d * d;
  }
  double rms = sqrt(sum_d2 / SIZE);
  printf("RMS Frequency: %f\n", rms);
  return 0;
}
```